Getting fatal: reference is not a tree: <commitid>
I have a link to a repo thisRepo with commit id : https://github.com/user/thisRepo/tree/<commitid>. When I use github to view the repo at this commit, I see 
I am trying to access the repo at this commit point using.
git checkout <commitid>, I get fatal: reference is not a tree: <commitid>
Just to add I have done git fetch for all branches for this user, after adding it to my remote. I am able to access other commit.

How did you get that commit id? Where is it coming from?

The user shared the commit id, so I wanted to pull that code.

Well.... It's either that that repo does not contain that commit or it's not "published" (repos will only expose commits that are part of history of a branch or tag in that repo).

You can the commit in its correct context by searching for it on gihub.com directly e.g.
hash:dce1e0b6daaa872a3b88724d9aa1b087c95e8754 type:commit.
This way you will find out if the commit id you were given is valid.
